# World coordinates as float to chunk and pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, grid

I have no idea right now for how to calculate pixel coordinates within the chunk.
I calculate the chunk from the world coordinates like this:

```
float xCoord = ..., yCoord = ...; //Can be positive and negative.
int xChunk = static_cast<int>(std::floor((xCoord + WORLD_OFFSET_X_F) / CHUNK_XY_SIZE_F));
int yChunk = static_cast<int>(std::floor((yCoord + WORLD_OFFSET_Y_F) / CHUNK_XY_SIZE_F));
```

It would be easy to calculate the pixel coordinates within the chunk if they were integers. Example:

```
int xCoord = ..., yCoord = ...; //Can be positive and negative.
int xPixel = (xCoord + WORLD_OFFSET_X_I) % CHUNK_XY_SIZE_I; Or by using the AND(&) operator.
int yPixel = (yCoord + WORLD_OFFSET_Y_I) % CHUNK_XY_SIZE_I;
```

This doesn't work by using floating point numbers. **How can I accomplish the same results with floating point numbers?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it exactly the same way. You just have to use a floating point modulo instead of integer. Take a look at [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)